Permission Error when trying to create a .txt file
Problem:
I have not been successful in simply creating a new .txt file onto my desktop.
I am truly at a loss. To be fair, I do not mess with files very much, so I am sure this is a simple solution. One weird thing that I have encountered is that it does create a folder instead of a file even though it has the file extension provided. From what I have researched though, this is very common.
I would not have asked this question if I could not already find it on this website, but I think my situation is a little unique.
I have tried multiple different methods including the following:

Running Idle as administrator.
Creating a folder on the desktop and saving the file there.
Going into each individual .py file and making sure they have permissions.

Code:
desktop_path = pathlib.Path.home() / 'OneDrive' / 'Desktop'
print (desktop_path)

def save_data():   
        file_name = last+'_'+first+'_'+'Symptom Checklist 90-R Results.txt'
        file_path = Path(os.path.join(desktop_path, file_name))
        
        table = tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid")
        
        os.makedirs(file_path, exist_ok=True)
        print(file_path)
        try:
            with open(file_path,'w') as file:
                file.write(first_name+"\n"+last_name+"\n"+age+"\n"+birthday+"\n")
                file.write(table)
            file.close()
        except PermissionError:
            print("You do not have access to create this file.")

Here are what the print statements execute:
C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop
C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop\__Symptom Checklist 90-R Results.txt
You do not have access to create this file.

Again, I am sure this is a simple solution, and I am just blind to see it. I have also made sure that this file name doesn't already exist for whatever reason.

Can you add a trailing slash after 'Desktop'. You are now writing a file named Desktop_something to the one drive directory

You should do file_path = desktop_path / file_name.  That's the beauty of Path.  However, I'm unclear why os.path.join didn't work.

@sleepyhead. That's weird, the print statement should look like this:
C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop__Symptom Checklist 90-R Results.txt
There is a trailing slash, I guess I just didn't copy and paste that.

change os.makedirs(file_path, exist_ok=True) to os.makedirs(file_path.parent, exist_ok=True)

It looks like you are running this code as a user account that does not have permission to write to that folder.

Thank you all for your insight and help. I ended up following this example found here: https://www.codeease.net/programming/python/how-to-run-python-script-as-admin
The first solution provided me with an easy solution. All I had to do was simply add this line: os.system(f'runas /user:Administrator "{file_path}"')

Maybe try running the python file from admin terminal.

Open the admin terminal by right clicking the start button and then selecting command prompt (admin)
Then run the file from that terminal by: python [filename].py


Thank you. I tried to run Idle as administrator and it didn't work. What I ended up doing though was adding the line: os.system(f'runas /user:Administrator "{file_path}"').
That ended up working for me. Thank you again.
